# I have post id, comments ids, how to get single comment id in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a method in my **posts model** that gets the comments for the currect post:

```
public function get_comments($post_id) {

        $this->db->select('id, post_id, rating_count, author_name, author_email, posted_date, comment')->from('comments')->where('post_id', $post_id)->order_by("posted_date", "desc")->limit(100);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

I am using it in my **post controller**. For every comment bellow the post content I have comments and all the comments have + and - button for likes and dislikes.

I my **view** I have all fields for the row:

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
```

and when I have link like this:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url().'posts/' . 
$posts_item['slug'] . '/' . $comment['id'] . '/like'; ?>" class="positive">+</a>
```

I finally get URL like this:

**posts/second-post-cool-title/3/like**

and this 3 is my comment ID.

I am trying to create a functions that use this ID in order to insert records in DB for the likes and dislikes.

I then go back to my controller, create a function like this:

```
public function like() {
/*
I am trying to get the comment id and use it here
*/

}
```

...and I am trying to access the comment id and record +1 vote in the dabatase, but the current comment id is accessible for me only in my view (in a foreach loop) passed by the model.

How can i create a function that has access to the current comment id. I can only see it in the generated URL address. Do I miss something in general? Do i have to use $_GET to read directly from the URL or there is another way. If I have to use GET how I will able to access the ID from a URL like ths one: posts/second-post-cool-title/3/like

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Could you not just use a URL like: /controller/like/{comment_id}?
In that case, the like() method would accept {comment_id} as a parameter which you could use in your query to create the association.

Comment: Thank you very much! :) I really had to reverse the ID and the function in the link and everything works the classic controller/function/args way. :) This is my first time with CI but I had to be more carefull :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$postId = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

Might be off by one in the segment number honestly if 3 doesn't work try 2 lol.

Comment: Thanx! This worked as a charm! But I have really mistaken the logic of this action. I had to reverse the ID and the method and my URL is now /controller/like/{comment_id} like jcorry suggested in the comment on my question above! 
:)

Comment: Glad it helped. To be honest though there was no actual need to change the URL. CI can grab any segment using the code above. I just tend to screw up which segment it is (hence the might be off comment). It's very useful when passing multiple parameters via the URL.